# ErrorException : `file_put_contents(/home/iyqexduam/alumni/storage/framework/cache/ : in live severs

Tags: php, laravel, server, cpanel

ErrorException `file_put_contents(/home/iyqexduam/alumni/storage/framework/cache/data/8b/64/8b648223b9e811082960f14ffa499b5354c120ab): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

I logged in my admin panel many times... Suddenly i am getting this error.. when i try to log in it's happening... I clear cache and run all this command also

```
 Artisan::call('config:cache');
 Artisan::call('config:clear');
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
Artisan::call('view:clear');
Artisan::call('route:clear');
 Artisan::call('clear-compiled');
```

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 storage`

Comment: where or how i run this command ?

Comment: via ssh or if you have file manager you can give 777 permission to storage folder

Comment: i search it on `sudo chmod -R 777 storage` google .. i found about this.. it is not safe.. there is alternate ...

Comment: then use 755 ...

Comment: i need to try tit... thanks